# How can public IP address of cloud VMs remains same even if cloud VM gets migrated to another data centre?

Tags: networking

Let us assume, I have hosted my Application on any cloud and want to migrate to AWS for the XYZ reason.
In the previous DATA centre, I have the public IP address assign for cloud VMs (Application).
Now if I'm migrating to AWS I want the same Ip address as the existing one.
So how we can achieve this as a network engineer.

CSP must ensure that the public IP address of cloud VMs remains the same even if the cloud VM network is being served from multiple CSP data centres.

Comment: IP addresses are assigned to/owned by the cloud vendor. When you change vendors, you cannot keep the IP address loaned to the VMs in your account when you move to another cloud. Global load balancers can minimize the impact, but they are also cloud specific. Therefore, your goal `CSP must ensure that the public IP address ...` is not realistic.

Answer (score 0):

There may be two situation

1. You want to change your cloud vendor. In this case, public IP can't be the same.
2. If you want to change the region to a single Cloud provider and use the same IP across all regions e.g; AWS.
   then you have to create the Elastic IP with Global static IP addresses.

[image]